# Are there any limits on transaction chain?

Tags: opendaylight

I tried to use transaction chain instead of data broker to create all transactions for the runtime of the product but failed with indication that the chain does not exist anymore.
The question is if transaction chain can produce only limited number of transactions or the lifetime of the chain has some limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit to the number of transactions but if a single transaction fails then that fails the whole chain and renders it unusable. Hence the reason for passing in a TransactionChainListener. The javadocs provide the details.